# bs4 not picking up class?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

(I am very new to python)

I am trying to extract all champions from a League of Legends roster. But it seems to not be able to find the class I'm searching for (rt-tr-group)

This is the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from requests import get

#   requests

url = 'https://u.gg/lol/tier-list'
response = get(url)
#print(response.text[:500])

#   bs4

html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
type(html_soup)

movie_containers = html_soup.find_all('div', class_ = r"rt-tr-group")
print(type(movie_containers))
print(movie_containers)
print(len(movie_containers))
```

This outputs

```
<class 'bs4.element.ResultSet'>
[]
0
```

When it should output:

```
<class 'bs4.element.ResultSet'>
[*all the cases with class_=rt-tr-group*]
30
```

Why does it output *an empty array* and *0* ?

Comment: Did you check if the elements you want to extract are included in `response.text`? It looks like the content you want to extract is dynamically loaded via javascript, so a plain HTTP GET request cannot find that information.

Comment: @NiklasMertsch it seems that it is not. It looks like it's a sub-class if you can call it that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='c:/program/geckodriver.exe')

url = 'https://u.gg/lol/tier-list'
driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)


movie_containers = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.rt-tr-group')
print(type(movie_containers))
print(movie_containers)
print(len(movie_containers))
driver.close()
```

prints:

```
<class 'list'>
[<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="e9cb0ff8-be4b-44fc-9174-2e419ee98b7d", element="01fbfcb3-bcda-4b80-ab16-b9c4c7064a44")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="e9cb0ff8-be4b-44fc-9174-2e419ee98b7d", element="f6b105e7-4115-4858-bf9a-8b49d545836b")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="e9cb0ff8-be4b-44fc-9174-2e419ee98b7d", element="3df5237c-be61-4ad6-83f4-90fe61ce321b")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="e9cb0ff8-be4b-44fc-9174-2e419ee98b7d", element="9e7dd15b-30af-4c35-b7be-211008307d57")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="e9cb0ff8-be4b-44fc-9174-2e419ee98b7d", element="7e520eb4-b9fc-47f4-bbeb-18a093fc4014")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="e9cb0ff8-be4b-44fc-9174-2e419ee98b7d", element="2ac35d20-a02d-4b57-a69d-df94c7960a72")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="e9cb0ff8-be4b-44fc-9174-2e419ee98b7d", element="03019e3d-3a8b-4c97-a924-499b6fcfe2a8")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="e9cb0ff8-be4b-44fc-9174-2e419ee98b7d", element="0cc7652c-cb7a-45c7-8f75-131d2dd1b297")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="e9cb0ff8-be4b-44fc-9174-2e419ee98b7d", element="07c070ad-766f-4c06-af86-99af454cdb60")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="e9cb0ff8-be4b-44fc-9174-2e419ee98b7d", element="a1773fd7-1f6f-4e13-b8db-a9ebc377585c")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="e9cb0ff8-be4b-44fc-9174-2e419ee98b7d", element="660bc4d4-2861-4245-8d6b-f7c98b4ec79d")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="e9cb0ff8-be4b-44fc-9174-2e419ee98b7d", element="4416ca86-87ad-40a0-a013-9622849bdf00")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="e9cb0ff8-be4b-44fc-9174-2e419ee98b7d", element="36df65b0-8251-4568-b1d8-ae038ba8cc33")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="e9cb0ff8-be4b-44fc-9174-2e419ee98b7d", element="5396a9bc-86e8-42a8-b9ab-27f3ed3d2af2")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="e9cb0ff8-be4b-44fc-9174-2e419ee98b7d", element="f7c874af-1494-4230-abfb-52cc437caeb7")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="e9cb0ff8-be4b-44fc-9174-2e419ee98b7d", element="bee789cb-d02e-4501-aa7c-978abd1118cd")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="e9cb0ff8-be4b-44fc-9174-2e419ee98b7d", element="df777a62-0ca3-40e9-bcd0-91730cbd3d7a")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="e9cb0ff8-be4b-44fc-9174-2e419ee98b7d", element="0ec5a92b-3c84-4ca9-a80c-965303f63fee")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="e9cb0ff8-be4b-44fc-9174-2e419ee98b7d", element="4f2ebf56-4c5a-45d6-96ca-a2c7cbd7f977")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="e9cb0ff8-be4b-44fc-9174-2e419ee98b7d", element="a664b073-09cf-467d-a891-23dbf852f023")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="e9cb0ff8-be4b-44fc-9174-2e419ee98b7d", element="915fee4c-f94a-4aa4-98af-798a650fbfb9")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="e9cb0ff8-be4b-44fc-9174-2e419ee98b7d", element="23e3e2e5-9c60-46f9-b479-8da1d70d999a")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="e9cb0ff8-be4b-44fc-9174-2e419ee98b7d", element="2a71b65c-131a-4f24-959b-99f391492707")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="e9cb0ff8-be4b-44fc-9174-2e419ee98b7d", element="4968e326-dc94-401b-bd2a-7b1b1bf279a8")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="e9cb0ff8-be4b-44fc-9174-2e419ee98b7d", element="c23d9860-d810-49b1-a07b-db0f1a2f0f3f")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="e9cb0ff8-be4b-44fc-9174-2e419ee98b7d", element="b0729826-fd0a-4316-923b-d64a9d576b46")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="e9cb0ff8-be4b-44fc-9174-2e419ee98b7d", element="71c74203-adcc-450a-a35d-667746c195f6")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="e9cb0ff8-be4b-44fc-9174-2e419ee98b7d", element="01305329-31d2-4885-a003-9e4c9a0b7fa7")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="e9cb0ff8-be4b-44fc-9174-2e419ee98b7d", element="108e2c8a-23a2-4904-a597-9cebb28766c1")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="e9cb0ff8-be4b-44fc-9174-2e419ee98b7d", element="d9088584-5b35-4743-a191-1841df806977")>]
30
```

Note yo need [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) and [geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) and in this code geckodriver is set to be imported from `c:/program/geckodriver.exe`

Answer (score 0):

`requests.get(url)` sends a HTTP GET request. The result roughly is what you get via right-clicking a website and choosing "Show Page Source".

[Your target website](https://u.gg/lol/tier-list) however generates its content dynamically via Javascript when your browser's web engine interprets the HTML result of HTTP GET. So the information you are looking for is not contained in `response.text` and beautifulsoup can therefore not find it there.

You could use a web browser automation tool like [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/), which has great [Python bindings](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) and also a great [guide](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html).

Answer (score 0):

This website is dynamically loaded. When looking to all requests, you should find what you are looking to using a network monitor (for example, in firefox press `CTRL+SHIFT+E` to monitore all requests)

With such a tool, you can directly use this API :
https://static.u.gg/assets/lol/riot_static/10.15.1/data/en_US/champion.json

Answer (score 0):

I have actually done this exact thing before. Pulling data from u.gg for one's own purposes is not easy.
As others have stated, the data is loaded dynamically, AKA from javascript. This means you need to pull it from the source that the javascript gets it from.

However.

U.gg stores its data in really, **really** messy and unlabeled json files which are a pain to go through. All champions, tiers, ranks, roles, etc are simply assigned a number and stored as such. This around 9 months ago when I ran into this so some of it may have changed, but I highly doubt it. So for that reason, I highly recommend using a loading tool like Selenium to have the values parsed and loaded and then you can scrape them from the page itself, rather than trying to spend hours deciphering the u.gg json like I did.